# Progress 4GL query

Tags: progress-4gl

I have a table say 'Employee' with one single field say 'Name'. There are say 9 records in the table. I need to write a 'for each' query with the help of 'where' clause by which i will be able to view/display one selected name (say 'Sheldon' being the 6th record of the 9) at the very first and the rest 8 records(names) in alphabetical order.
**Note: Only by constructing a query as such. No concept of temp-tables, buffers. nothing allowed within the 'for each' block other than 'display' statement.

Comment: You said "one selected name". What is "selected" here? On what basis a name is selected?

Comment: This is a fairly strange set of requirements.  I'm curious, would you care to elaborate on why you need these peculiar restrictions?

Comment: First of all, i need to know whether what i jus asked is possible or not xactly in the way i framed! And i dint need these peculiar restriction unless an interviewer claimed with confidence that this can be done and I being curious is driving possibilities!

Comment: anything is possible depending on what you want too do.

Comment: So we're answering interview questions for you?  Cool.  How much of a commission do we get?

Comment: FWIW -- if it is possible it uses vile trickery.  If I were to use this as an interview it would be to weed out dangerous lunatics that should never be allowed near a code editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are saying that you have an employee table with records like:

```
Dan
Gus
Mike
Paul
Rich
Sheldon
Shelley
William
Xavier
```

And you want the output to be:

```
Sheldon
Dan
Gus
Mike
Paul
Rich
Shelley
William
Xavier
```

You cannot do this in a single FOR EACH because you have two quite distinct queries.  One to find the "sheldon" record (or records -- you didn't say if they are unique) and one to find all of the rest.

You could do it like so:

```
do with frame a.
  for each employee no-lock where name = "Sheldon":
    display name with frame a 10 down.
    down with frame a.
  end.
  for each employee where name <> "Sheldon" by name:
    display name with frame a.
    down with frame a.
  end.
end.
```

(The "do with frame a" and various other "frame a" bits are just to use a single frame.  If you don't care about that you don't need those bits.)

If you are willing to expand your horizons a bit and stoop to using FIND you could do it like so:

```
find employee no-lock where name = "sheldon".

repeat:

  if not available employee then leave.

  display name with 10 down.

  if name = "sheldon" then
    find first employee no-lock where name <> "sheldon" no-error.
   else
    find next employee where name <> "sheldon" no-error.

end.
```

Comment: Perhaps consider doing `IF name = "Sheldon" THEN NEXT` in the second loop to avoid table scans? Perhaps not lethal for this example but might be for other queries.

Comment: If you are scanning darn near the whole thing anyway it is no big deal.

Comment: That's a good point! (But you could add the TABLE-SCAN option if you're on a new release...)

Comment: I added a simple FIND based method just for kicks and grins.

Comment: A rule of thumb that I've heard tossed around (but not tested) is that if you are reading more than roughly 10% of the table you may as well just do a table scan anyway.  Like all rules of thumb it is likely bogus at some level -- but it's an interesting thing to mull over.

Comment: @TomBascom I await your findings on this with eager anticipation ;)

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reasons I haven't spent much time testing this but the vile trickery appears to be:

```
for each employee where name = "sheldon" or name <> "sheldon":
  display name.
end.
```

As I said -- I'd use this as a disqualifying test.  If you think like this then your code is more trouble than it is worth.  IMHO.

Comment: I could not agree more!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd use a FIND for this, but since you asked for a FOR EACH - here's one w/out the WHERE. You can easily add that to get any end result you want.

```
FOR EACH employee  
    NO-LOCK 
    BY Employee.name:

    DISPLAY employee.name WITH DOWN.

END.
```

Comment: This really doesnt produce what was asked: a specific name first and the rest in alphabetical order after...

Comment: His requirements are contradictory - only one "for each", one display statement, show a give name first, followed by all the other names in the table besides the cited name, in ascending order. 

What he wants can't be done. Given this, I'm positing he's extremely new to the language, so I wrote the above with the option that he could then "season to taste" as it were.

Comment: hi @TimKuehn, I agree I am very new to this language at least wrt you. I wil drive my short introduction then, 2yrs 2 months in Progress while programming concept is driving me for no less than 6 years. I demanded this cannot be done the way the interviewer asked me (which is pretty much my 'Question' here) at least he cud have allowed to listen to my concept of using _buffer_ but his demand was unshakable and so I chose this forum to get a possible ans from world of genius'!!

Comment: Glad to help out - you need to upvote the comments that've helped you here, and mark one of them as the "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Use two for eaches. first one returns from your selected name and larger alphabetical and the 2nd starts from beginning and breaks as soon as get to your selected name.
This will display fields alphabetically starting at your selected name. This assume name is alphabetically sorted key field else can use other options to sort values.

Sorry did not test code, or worry about formatting. Also not sure by what you mean the rest must be alphabetically so here are two variations.

With using a temp table it would be even easier to do any 1 of these approaches.

Should be like this if you want to show sheldon and then alpha from sheldon onwards:

```
FOR EACH employee  where name >= "sheldon" NO-LOCK:
    DISPLAY employee.name.
END.

FOR EACH employee  NO-LOCK:
    if employee.name = "sheldon"
        break;
    DISPLAY employee.name.
END.
```

Should be like this if you want to show sheldon and then alpha from start, excluding sheldon:

```
FIND employee no-lock where name = "sheldon".
DISPLAY employee.name.

FOR EACH employee  NO-LOCK where name <> "sheldon":
    DISPLAY employee.name.
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively non-evil way, for the record, which is safe against future releases of Openedge screwing with you:

```
for each employee 
    no-lock
    by (if employee.name = "sheldon" then 1 else 2)
    by employee.name
:
    display employee.
end.
```

...but the performance will be horrible.